Voltage controlled current source design
I'm working on a project where I need to design a bipolar current source controlled by a sinusoidal voltage between -1.25 V and 1.25 V. It has to deliver a maximum bipolar sinusoidal signal between -4 mA and 4 mA through a variable load (between 1-5 kΩ).
I'm interested in the following design I found in the Application notes 47 of Analog Devices, page 65:

My question is: how can I design it to have the desired output current for my project? Which resistor, capacitor and power supply values should I use? (I can also modify the input voltage, specifically, it could be increased until a max value of 5 V peak-to-peak).

Neus Pons Andres - you don't appear to have understood the points made in answers to your previous question. 10 kohm and +/-4 mA necessarily means a supply rail of at least 80 volts and, quite possibly 90 volts (as per my answer).

Yes, I understood, I wanted to know how to configure/design this circuit to be able to give a current through a variable load. Let's say we want to have a maximum power supply of +-24V, then the current through the load will be 4mA if its value is 5kOhm or less, but that is fine. I just wanted to know how to do the design. Thanks

@NeusPonsAndrés, please edit the question to clarify the requirements so people don't have to go through the comments (or previous questions) to understand. As described now the reference design you mentioned (low voltage / high current) seems to contradict what is needed.

You don't need any of the buffering transistors and their periphery, since you only need 4mA of output current. Almost every op-amp has a push-pull output stage capable of sinking and sourcing 4mA.
±4mA through 5kΩ would require ±20V of output swing, something that not many op-amps can do. Also, most op-amp outputs will fall short of their supply potentials, so you'll need supplies that exceed ±20V, perhaps ±25V, and that will require a rather special op-amp, such as the OPA551, which will handle many tens of milliamps of output, and can work with supplies up to ±30V. A slower, weaker (but still capable of 4mA) and cheaper alternative would be the LTC2057HV.
If you don't require the load to be grounded on one side, then a solution could be as simple as this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Using the values shown, this circuit produces current \$I_{OUT}\$ as a function of \$V_{IN}\$:
$$ I_{OUT} = \frac{V_{IN}}{R_1} $$
Therefore, using the values shown, an input of ±0.88V will produce maxima of ±4mA load current.
Sense resistance R1 must not develop more than 1V at full current:
$$ R_1 \le \frac{1V}{I_{OUT(MAX)}} $$
If the load must be grounded, then current sensing must take place at the output of OA1. In keeping with the design you suggested, it can be modified to use a second op-amp configured as a differential amplifier:

simulate this circuit
This design has the same input-to-output relationship as the first, but will be slightly less accurate, due to the lower input impedance
of the current sense amplifier. However, as long as you use very tight tolerance resistors, or measure and use only those that fall within 0.25% of their rated value, you could still achieve better than 1% accuracy.
Update
To calculate the resistances needed to convert some range of input voltage to the ±4mA output range, we'll start by assuming that the sense resistance \$R_1=220\Omega\$ won't change, since this will develop a voltage \$V_S\$:
$$ V_S = R_1I_{OUT} $$
At the extremes of ±4mA, this corresponds to:
$$ V_S = 220\Omega \times \pm 4mA = \pm 0.88V $$
This value should be small, less than a volt or so, because this "drop" will reduce the maximum compliance voltage swing available to the load. The differential amplifier (OA2 and its periphery) will multiply that potential difference \$V_S\$ by some gain \$k\$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
k &= \frac{R_2}{R_3} = \frac{R_4}{R_5} \\ \\
V_Q &= kV_S
\end{aligned}
$$
The loop around OA1 is closed in a negative feedback arrangement, which causes OA1 to adjust its output to whatever potential is required to produce the condition:
$$ V_Q = V_{IN} $$
That's the last equation needed to characterise the circuit's behaviour. By combining them all, we have a single equation from which we can derive resistance values:
$$
\begin{aligned}
k &= \frac{R_2}{R_3} \\ \\
kV_S &= V_Q \\ \\
&= V_{IN} \\ \\
V_S\frac{R_2}{R_3} &= V_{IN} \\ \\
R_1I_{OUT}\frac{R_2}{R_3} &= V_{IN} \\ \\
\frac{R_3}{R_2} &= R_1\frac{I_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Now you can plug in some known values for \$V_{IN}\$ and the corresponding expected \$I_{OUT}\$, and find the ratio \$\frac{R_3}{R_2}\$. For instance:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{IN} &= +5V \\ \\
I_{OUT} &= +4mA \\ \\
\frac{R_3}{R_2} &= 220\Omega \frac{4\times 10^{-3}A}{5V} \\ \\
&= 0.176
\end{aligned}
$$
Guessing a value of \$R_3=R_5=47k\Omega\$, that produces:
$$ R_2 = R_4 = \frac{R_3}{0.176} = \frac{47k\Omega}{0.176} = 267k\Omega $$
It may be possible to use a regular ±16V (32V) op-amp for OA2, if its inputs and outputs never fall outside ±13V or so. You'd need to further analyse the circuit to determine if that's the case. It's easier and more practical to avoid the need for a separate low voltage dual supply just for OA1, and use another high-voltage device like the OPA551 or LTC2057HV with the same ±25V supply.
You've already come across the improved Howland current pump (see fig. 2 on that page), as I see from your previous question, but I'll include it here using components that would work given the constraints of this new question:

simulate this circuit
Input and output are related as follows:
$$ I_{OUT} = V_{IN}\frac{k}{R_5}, \rm{\ where\ } k=\frac{R_2}{R_1}=\frac{R_4}{R_3} $$

Hi, thank you for your answer. However, the load is going to be grounded, how would be the circuit in this case?

@NeusPonsAndrés unfortunately that will require another op-amp or in-amp, which it will have the same voltage requirements as the OPA551 I used. The circuit doubles or even triples in complexity instantly. I can't see any simple alternative, I'm afraid. I only suggested this circuit because there was some chance you could use a single higher-voltage op-amp.

Hi Simon, thank you so much for your answer. I've been working on your circuit and trying different values for the input sinusoidal signal using the arbitrary SPICE model for the op amp that KiCad offers. However, I can't make the circuit work when I replace the op amps by different high voltage supply op amps models, such as OPA551 or OPA454. Do you know how to solve this? I would like to implement this design in a PCB for my project but I would like to simulate it first.  Thank you so much in advance.

@NeusPonsAndrés Try getting it to work in LTspice first. The op-amp models in that simulator worked for me. It's harder in Kicad because you have to get the symbol pin-outs to match the imported spice models. Kicad's symbol definitions don't necessarily match the pin assignments for spice models coming from PSpice or LTspice. Diode symbols in Kicad, for example, swap anode and cathode terminals, which is a pain, but not difficult to rectify.

Hi, thank you. I've been using LTspice and it works. How have you designed the resistor values? My problem is that now I want so replace the sinusoidal voltage source with a DAC, whose output will be a sinusoidal. Therefore, I would like to have a higher peak-to-peak voltage (ideally around 5 to 10V) so that the signal generated can be more precise. How can I know how to choose the resistor values to handle an input voltage signal of 8V, for instance? Thank you so much in advance for your help

@NeusPonsAndrés Which design?

Hi, the one where the load is grounded. Thanks

@NeusPonsAndrés I've added the procedure and reasoning for calculating the resistances. Look for the "Update".

Thank you so much Simon, It was very useful. Could you deriver the relationship between Ix, Vin and Rload? I haven't been able to figure it out. Thanks in advance

@NeusPonsAndrés OA2, R2, R3, R4 and R5 form a differential amplifier, for which there must be a thousand websites explaining its function, and deriving gain, such as this one and this other one. That's the only part I skipped in my derivation of $\frac{R_3}{R_2}=R_1\frac{I_{OUT}}{V_{IN}}$.

Thank you so much Simon. The problem is that when I simulate it, the current through the load is slightly lower than the theoretically calculated current that goes through the sense resistor. Why could that be? Is it because the circuit slightly depends on the Rl load? And how can I find the mathematical relationship that explains that?

@NeusPonsAndrés this is no doubt due to the non-infinite input impedance of the differential amplifier. Those inputs draw a tiny current away from the load. That's why R3 and R5 should be very large compared to R1. You can get better results using an in-amp (with much higher input impedance) as the original AD design did, but then you'd have to find one that can handle a ±25V supply, which is the original problem I tried to address.

Thank you so much Simon.  If I want to use an instrumentation amplifier, would the connections in the schematics be the same as using the op amps you proposed?

@NeusPonsAndrés The simplest solution I can think of is to measure the actual current using an ammeter, and compensate for the offset and scaling errors due to this problem at the input side, $V_{IN}$. It might be possible to scale and offset the input using another op-amp to mitigate the error to a great degree. This is why electronic engineers get paid the not-quite-big-enough bucks.

@NeusPonsAndrés Yes, to use an in-amp, it would replace the entire diff-amp section consisting of OA2, and R2 to R5. That is, two inputs (either side of R1), one output at Q. Usually you set gain of the in-amp with a single resistor that would depend on the model, and you'd replace $k$ in my equations with that gain.

Thank you so much Simon. I have been simulating the design with higher values of R5 and R3 (500k) and the problem improves a bit. Do you think it is a good practise? Thank you so much in advance, I am novel in this and I am trying to properly understand everything.

@NeusPonsAndrés It will be better for you to study a while, and perhaps ask further questions officially on the site. For example, you can ask about the pros and cons of using high value resistors in a diff-amp, but be sure to do some study first. I think the main question here is answered, and everything else is another topic altogether.

This design is unsuited for your application (high voltage/low current) as it is made for a low voltage/high current application, not yours.
I suggest you might want to adapt a TI reference design, and make something similar to this one:

Do not attempt to subsitute U1 unless you fully understand what you are doing- in fact the singular nature of the INA149 is probably what prompted the maker to publish this document since it will sell devices.
U1 has a very wide common-mode input range (+/-275V) and the transistors are used to bootstrap U1's supply to the required output voltage. Otherwise, it is a Howland current pump.
Alternatively, you could use an op-amp that allows much higher supply rails and simplify the design.

I liked the previous design (low voltage/high current) because of the push-pull configuration of the transistors, which allow for giving a bipolar current signal independent from the load.  Are there any ways of changing the op amps and the R, C values in order to adapt that design to my requirements? Instead of completely changing it?

@NeusPonsAndrés All op-amps have push-pull outputs built-in, and almost all can easily handle 4mA, so the whole output buffer arrangement is probably not necessary. 4mA through 5kΩ is 20V, so you'll need an op-amp that can output ±20V, which usually requires supplies closer to ±23V (a 46V potential difference). Your problem isn't current, it's voltage. There's no easy solution other than finding an op-amp that can work with 46V, or bootstrapping the op-amp supply as Spehro suggests. Either way, you probably don't need any of that high-current buffer paraphernalia in the first place.

The original circuit is a Howland pump. It is push-pull as it needs to be in order to deliver bipolar current to the load. The changes above are to accomodate high voltage. The main concern with your 4mA is chip dissipation. At +/-60V the chip would dissipate additional 240mW delivering 4mA into 0Ω, which is not terrible. The circuit you show does not boost voltage, only current, so it's inappropriate even as a  starting point.

Here , for example, is a HV op-amp (+/-90V). Depending on how firm your requirements are you might want to allow for a bit extra headroom. It would be sad to build the device and find you needed more current and/or more maximum resistance.

Personally, I'd just brute-force it by buying an LTC 2057 from someplace like Digikey. Since you need +/- 20 volts across your load, I'd use a +/- 24 volt supply, although the op amp can accept +/- 30. At 5 mA load, it only needs a half volt of headroom, so using something like a 100 ohm current sense resistor is possible. These things are about 4 bucks apiece, so that shouldn't be an issue. They are not fast, but you didn't indicate a need for high bandwidth.

Below is the LTspice sim of a Howland constant-current circuit that meets your current and load resistance requirements:
Note the constant peak current of 4mA (red trace) for a load resistance going from 1mΩ to 5kΩ (yellow trace).

